# Domain of the function $F(x)=\int_0^x(te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}})dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I know that the domain of the function $F(x)=\int_0^x(te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}})dt$ is the set of $x$ such as $F(x)$ is integrable.

The function $f(x)=te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, so first of all I have to prove that $F(x)$ is integrable as $x\rightarrow 0^+$, which is true.

How do I calculate the complete domain of $F(x)$?

**Update:** maybe I should solve the integral as $\lim_{m\to \infty}\int_0^mf(x)$ and see for which $m$ the integral converges.

Comment: Formally, the function $f: t \mapsto te^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}$ is not even defined in $t=0$, so when you say $f$ is continuous in $t=0$, you must have "done" something clever. Explain that. Once you know the integrand is continuous everywhere, it is also integrable over any interval, and then $F(x)$ is well-defined for any real $x$.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is finite for every $x$ so the domain is $\mathbb R$. [For $x<0$ $F(x)=-\int_x^{0} te^{-1/t^{2}} \, dt$].

Comment: But it does not converge as $x\rightarrow \infty$, am I wrong?

Comment: For finding the domain of $F$ you only have to see what what fixed values of $x$ the integral exists. You don't have to consider limits at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Sorry I know that it is an old answer but I have a doubt! The fact that I have no problem for $x=0$ is due by the fact that the integrand converges as $x\to 0^{\pm}$ and so the integral is well defined, right?

Comment: @cely There is  no problem with integrability. Near $0$ use the fact that $|te^{-1/t^{2}} | \leq |t|$.